# Why is the state of my activity not changing?

Tags: moryx

I want to execute a self written activity during an operation.

For that I created a Cell

```cs
[ResourceRegistration]
public class AssemblingCell : Cell
{
   ...
 
   public override IEnumerable<Session> ControlSystemAttached()
   {
       yield return Session.StartSession(ActivityClassification.Production, ReadyToWorkType.Push);
   }

   public override void SequenceCompleted(SequenceCompleted completed)
   {
       var rtw = Session.StartSession(ActivityClassification.Production, ReadyToWorkType.Push);
       PublishReadyToWork(rtw);
   }

   ...  
}
```

and a matching activity

```cs
[ActivityResults(typeof(DefaultActivityResult))]
public class AssemblingActivity : Activity<AssemblingParameters>
{
        public override ProcessRequirement ProcessRequirement => ProcessRequirement.Required;

        public override ICapabilities RequiredCapabilities => new AssemblingCapabilities();

        protected override ActivityResult CreateResult(long resultNumber)
        {
            return ActivityResult.Create((DefaultActivityResult)resultNumber);
        }

        protected override ActivityResult CreateFailureResult()
        {
            return ActivityResult.Create(DefaultActivityResult.Failed);
        }
}
```

I created an instance of the cell in the UI and started a production using a workplan, which only contains the `AssemblingActivity`.

The activity gets created and is in the state `initial`. But it never changes its state, although the cell sent a `ReadyToWork`. I checked if both the cell and the activity are matching, using the endpoint `<applicationUrl>/api/moryx/processes/running`. Since the cell is listed as a target for the activity, this is not the issue.

I expect that after a matching resource sent a `ReadyToWork`, the state of the Activity changes to `Ready` and later `Running`. The Cell then receives an `ActivityStarted` and can start with its work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have
`ProcessRequirement.Required` in your Activity, your cell needs to send the ReadyToWork with the ProcessId. Or you could just change `ProcessRequirement.Required` to `ProcessRequirement.NotRequired`
in your activity.